# Что будет хранится в ячейке NOT NULL столбца таблицы если не указать значение?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица *tb* с двумя полями *name* VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL и *surname* VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL. Что будет храниться в столбце name если не указать ему значение?
Допустим вот такой запрос SQL:

```
INSERT INTO tb(surname) VALUES('Jones');
```

Вылезет предупреждение: **Warning: #1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value.** 
И в поле name не будет записано NULL. А что тогда там будет храниться? Просто пустая строка? А если поле будет не строковым, а числовым, то тогда, что будет находиться в этой ячейке?

Comment: NOT NULL значит что нельзя туда ничего не записывать. Обязательно должно быть что-то. Иначе как-раз вам будут ошибку писать постоянно

Comment: Будет хранится то, что запишите.. А если ничего не записывать то будет ошибка и запись вы не вставите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Именно для mysql есть историческое поведение, контролируемое настройками так называемого [`strict sql mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict).

Если строгий режим выключен, что было историческим поведением этой СУБД до версии 5.7 - возможны многочисленные неожиданные сюрпризы в поведении. В частности, всего лишь предупреждение (warning) при попытке вставить значение в поле объявленное NOT NULL и не имеющее DEFAUL значение. В таблицу при этом будет записано некое значение которое СУБД сочтёт значением по-умолчанию для этого типа данных. Например, пустая строка для строковых типов данных, 0 для чисел. Есть и другие неожиданности, вроде тихого обрезания varchar(n) значений до значения n вместо сообщения об ошибке и аналогично запись максимально возможного для этого числового типа данных значения вместо сообщения с ошибкой о переполнении.

В строгом же режиме mysql ответит ошибкой в этих случаях и запись вставлена не будет вовсе, что является ожидаемой реакцией на некорректные действия пользователя. Настоятельно рекомендую использовать только strict sql mode, это убережёт от неожиданного поведения СУБД

Answer (score 0):

> И в поле name не будет записано NULL. А что тогда там будет храниться?

Там ничего не будет храниться, потому что даже запись в таблицу не вставится при таком ограничении (если только нет у столбца значения по умолчанию)

> А если поле будет не строковым, а числовым, то тогда, что будет находиться в этой ячейке?

Без разницы какого типа поле. Если поле объявлено как `NOT NULL`, то оно **обязано** хранить какое-либо значение. В ином случае записать в БД у вас не получится даже всю запись целиком, не смотря на то, что другие параметры все заполнены

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит о том, что поле "name" не имеет значения по умолчанию и запись невозможна по причине того, что Вы не указали значение для этого поля. В настройках таблицы уберите not null, либо установите значение по умолчанию, которое будет записано в случае, если в insert'е не будет указано значение.